# I can't create a trigger! Please correct it for me

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I need to create a trigger.

When I get a new tuple in the sales table,
its quantity should be decreased by 1 in stocks table.
However, this trigger doesn't work.
Please help!
Thank you.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER stock_update
AFTER INSERT ON sales
UPDATE stocks
SET st.quantity = st.quantity - 1
WHERE NEW.s_b_id = st_id;

CREATE TABLE stocks (
st_id int references books(b_id),
st_price money NOT NULL,
st_quantity int NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE sales (
order_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
s_b_id int NOT NULL references books(b_id),
s_a_id int NOT NULL references accounts(a_id),
s_price money NOT NULL,
s_date date NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: What RDBMS (SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, Postgres, ...) are you using? Implementation of triggers is **vendor-specific**.

Comment: Do you still need help with your question?

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL. Sorry, I was at school.

Comment: "this trigger doesn't work." is not a useful problem description. Please be specific about *how* it doesn't work. Do you get an error message? If so, what is it?

Comment: Thank you. I tried the answer below, and it works great. By the way, I can't drop the trigger. I tried "DROP TRIGGER stock_update_trigger;", but it said 'syntax error at or near ";"'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it this way

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION stock_update() 
RETURNS TRIGGER 
AS 
$stock_update$
BEGIN
  UPDATE stocks
     SET st_quantity = st_quantity - 1
   WHERE st_id = NEW.s_b_id;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$stock_update$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER stock_update_trigger 
AFTER INSERT ON sales 
FOR EACH ROW 
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE stock_update();
```

Let's try it:

```
# insert into stocks values (1, 20, 100);
INSERT 0 1

# insert into sales values(1, 1, 1, 20.00, '2013-12-10');                                             INSERT 0 1

# select * from stocks;
 st_id | st_price | st_quantity 
-------+----------+-------------
     1 |   $20.00 |          99
(1 row)
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/65fbd/1)** demo

---

**UPDATE:** to drop a trigger

```sql
DROP TRIGGER stock_update_trigger ON sales;
```

Comment: Thank you, it works great. By the way, how can I drop the trigger? I tried "DROP TRIGGER stock_update_trigger", but it doesn't work.